# Python datetime.strptime() ValueError

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I don't understand why I get this error using datetime.strptime(), shouldn't this match?

`ValueError: time data '2018-02-01 15:09:02.487779' does not match format '%Y-$m-$d %H:%M:%S.%f'`

Mimimal example would be:

```
from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.strptime('2018-02-01 15:09:02.487779', '%Y-$m-$d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have dollar signs instead of percent signs in parts of your format string:

```
print(datetime.strptime('2018-02-01 15:09:02.487779', '%Y-$m-$d %H:%M:%S.%f'))
                                                          ^  ^
```